# libreria zkteco9500 libzkfpcsharp.dll ERROR Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: c#, visual-studio, fingerprint, zkteco

I have a problem when reading the fingerprints on the zk9500, I get a memory error

[image]

I tried it with both x86 and x64 libraries but they give me the same error, at first it captures the fingerprint and shows it but after doing several fingerprint tests the error appears, perhaps the allowed memory is full and I should empty it with each fingerprint reading or maybe the value entered is null.

In addition, the data that enters the variables shown in the image are:

- FPBuffer = 90000
- CapTmp = 2048
- cbCapTmp = 2048
  For FPBuffer there are:
- mfpWidth = 300
- mfpHeight = 300

I'm use this demo [text](https://github.com/zaagan/ZKTecoFingerPrintScanner-Implementation) and I adapt it to my C# project, I use all your code as indicated

Could someone help me on how to debug to find the problem or I would also like if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please post your code and data as text, properly formatted, not as images

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an initialization problem. Fingerprint template that is read is not always of the same size so maybe you have some kind of buffer overrun. Also, I recommend using `zkfp2` object everywhere instead of a new instance of `zkfp`.

Please, try the following code:

```
private void DoCapture()
{
    byte[] fpBuffer = new byte[_fpWidth * _fpHeight];
    byte[] capTmp = new byte[2048];
    while (!_isTimeToDie)
    {
        int cbCapTmp = 2048;

        int ret = zkfp2.AcquireFingerprint(_devHandle, fpBuffer, capTmp, ref cbCapTmp);
        if (ret == zkfp.ZKFP_ERR_OK)
        {
            ProcessFingerPrint(fpBuffer, capTmp, cbCapTmp);
        }

        if (ret != zkfp.ZKFP_ERR_CAPTURE && ret != zkfp.ZKFP_ERR_OK)
            OnDriverError(ret, string.Empty);

        Thread.Sleep(200);
    }
}
```

both `_fpWidth` and `_fpHeight` are retrieved the same way as the demo, and `_devHandle` is the result of `zkfp2.OpenDevice(0)`.

By using `zkfp2` everywhere (instead a creating a new instance of `zkfp`) you have to make some other changes in the demo code as well.

For example, to open the device, use `_devHandle = zkfp2.OpenDevice(0)` and to close it, `zkfp2.CloseDevice(_devHandle)`.

To initialize the library, use `zkfp2.Init()` and to terminate it, `zkfp2.Terminate()`.

To initialize the database, use `_dbHandle = zkfp2.DBInit()` and to free it, `zkfp2.DBFree(_dbHandle)`.

Also, make sure you are using the last version of the ZK Finger libraries.